# Kubernetes Rolling Update with Helm2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to perform a [Kubernetes Rolling Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) using [Helm v2](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/); however, I'm unable to.

When I perform a `helm upgrade` on a [slow Tomcat image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hqasem/slow-tomcat), the original pod is destroyed.

I would like to figure out how to achieve zero downtime by incrementally updating Pods instances with new ones, and draining old ones.

To demonstrate, I created a sample [slow Tomcat Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hqasem/slow-tomcat), and a [Helm chart](https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/).

### To install:

```
helm install https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/raw/master/docs/slowtom.tgz --name slowtom \
     -f https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/raw/master/docs/slowtom/environments/initial.yaml
```

You can follow the logs by running `kubectl logs -f slowtom-sf-0`, and once ready you can access the application on `http://localhost:30901`

### To upgrade:

#### (and that's where I need help)

```
helm upgrade slowtom https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/raw/master/docs/slowtom.tgz \
     -f https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/raw/master/docs/slowtom/environments/upgrade.yaml
```

The [`upgrade.yaml`](https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/blob/master/docs/slowtom/environments/upgrade.yaml) is identical to the [`initial.yaml`](https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/blob/master/docs/slowtom/environments/initial.yaml) deployment file with the exception of the tag version number.

Here the original pod is destroyed, and the new one starts. Meanwhile, users are unable to access the application on `http://localhost:30901`

#### To Delete:

```
helm del slowtom --purge
```

## Reference

### Local Helm Chart

#### Download helm chart:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/raw/master/docs/slowtom.tgz
tar vxfz ./slowtom.tgz
```

#### Install from local helm-chart:

```
helm install --debug ./slowtom --name slowtom -f ./slowtom/environments/initial.yaml
```

#### Upgrade from local helm-chart:

```
helm upgrade --debug slowtom ./slowtom -f ./slowtom/environments/upgrade.yaml
```

### Docker Image

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jdk8-corretto

RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT && \
    echo '<html><head><title>Slow Tomcat</title></head><body><h1>Slow Tomcat Now Ready</h1></body></html>' >> /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.html

RUN echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo 'x=2' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo 'secs=$(($x * 60))' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo 'while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo '   >&2 echo -e "Blast off in $secs\033[0K\r"' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo '   sleep 1' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo '   : $((secs--))' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo 'done' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo '>&2 echo "slow cataline done. will now start real catalina"' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    echo 'exec catalina.sh run' >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh 

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh"]
```

### Helm Chart Content

#### `slowtom/Chart.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
description: slow-tomcat Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: slowtom
version: 1.1.2  # whatever
```

#### `slowtom/values.yaml`

```
# Do not use this file, but ones from environmments folder
```

#### `slowtom/environments/initial.yaml`

```
# Storefront
slowtom_sf:
  name: "slowtom-sf"
  hasHealthcheck: "true"
  isResilient: "false"
  replicaCount: 2
  aspect_values:
    - name: y_aspect
      value: "storefront"

image:
  repository: hqasem/slow-tomcat
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: 1
env:
  - name: y_env
    value: whatever
```

#### `slowtom/environments/upgrade.yaml`

```
# Storefront
slowtom_sf:
  name: "slowtom-sf"
  hasHealthcheck: "true"
  isResilient: "false"
  replicaCount: 2
  aspect_values:
    - name: y_aspect
      value: "storefront"

image:
  repository: hqasem/slow-tomcat
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: 2
env:
  - name: y_env
    value: whatever
```

#### `slowtom/templates/deployment.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name | trunc 63 }}"
    chartVersion: "{{ .Chart.Version | trunc 63 }}" 
    visualize: "true" 
    app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.replicaCount }} 
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }}
        visualize: "true" 
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers: 
        - name: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh"]
          args: ["whatever"]
          env:
{{ toYaml .Values.env | indent 12 }}
{{ toYaml .Values.slowtom_sf.aspect_values | indent 12 }}
          resources: 
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
---
```

#### `slowtom/templates/service.yaml`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.slowtom_sf.name}} 
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name | trunc 63 }}"
    chartVersion: "{{ .Chart.Version | trunc 63 }}"
    app: {{.Values.slowtom_sf.name}}
    visualize: "true" 
    hasHealthcheck: "{{ .Values.slowtom_sf.hasHealthcheck }}" 
    isResilient: "{{ .Values.slowtom_sf.isResilient }}"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: {{.Values.slowtom_sf.name}}
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http
      nodePort: 30901
---
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include relevant bits of your Kubernetes manifest (`templates/deployment.yaml`)?  Kubernetes should handle this automatically when the `image:` in the pod spec template of a deployment spec changes.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added links to the [`initial.yaml`](https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/blob/master/docs/slowtom/environments/initial.yaml) and [`upgrade.yaml`](https://github.com/h-q/slowtom/blob/master/docs/slowtom/environments/upgrade.yaml) deployment files. They are identical with the exception of the tag / version number.

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] as text, in the question; not behind links (you're pretty likely to update your GitHub repo once you find a fix).

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for your feedback. I have added the necessary files.

Comment: Do you really need to use `StatefulSet` rather than `Deployment`? I've never had a problem doing this with vanilla deployments, but StatefulSet is a different beast

Comment: @superstator. I've updated the replicaCount to 2, but the same problem exist.

Comment: Have you tried just changing `kind: StatefulSet` to `kind: Deployment`?

Comment: @superstator. Yes I tried. Simply switching to `kind: Deployment` doesn’t work either. I have provided easy files to download and test yourself if you wish.

Comment: I am on helm 3.3 so I can't duplicate your setup exactly. Using my version, I just had to change the `kind:` value and remove the invalid `nodePort` settings from your containers, and it worked fine, including the rolling update.

Comment: @superstator I removed the invalid `nodePort`. Unfortunately it is not currently possible to upgrade Helm2 in my target system. But more importantly, I need to use `StatefulSet` to communicate with other pods. I appreciate if you can help me with Helm2 and `StatefulSet`. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect helm is a red herring here. What version of k8s are you deploying to?

Comment: @superstator currently we're at k8s v1.19.0. And I can upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding [Readiness or Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) to my `deployment.yaml`

#### `slowtom/templates/deployment.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name | trunc 63 }}"
    chartVersion: "{{ .Chart.Version | trunc 63 }}" 
    visualize: "true" 
    app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.replicaCount }} 
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }}
        visualize: "true" 
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers: 
        - name: {{ .Values.slowtom_sf.name }} 
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/slowcatalina.sh"]
          args: ["whatever"]
          env:
{{ toYaml .Values.env | indent 12 }}
{{ toYaml .Values.slowtom_sf.aspect_values | indent 12 }}
          resources: 
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
---
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `Deployment`, `StatefulSet` does not start a new pod before destroying the old one during a rolling update. Instead, the expectation is that you have multiple pods, and they will be replaced one-by-one. Since you only have 1 replica configured, it must destroy it first. Either increase your replica count to 2 or more, or switch to a `Deployment` template.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#rolling-update